# android button with half circle edges

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

I am trying to create a shape to be used for my imagebuttons in my Android project that would essentially have half circles for the left and right sides.

I thought I could just use a shape XML with a radius, but that just rounds the corners where I need the whole left and right sides to be half circles like the image below.

My current XML for the shape looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" 
    android:color="@color/white">

    <corners
       android:radius="60dip"
         />

    <stroke
        android:width="0dp"
        android:color="#000000" />


     <solid
        android:color="@color/white" />

</shape>
```

but I am trying to get this effect :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How tall is your button? The shape drawable with rounded corners should work, you want the radius to be half of the height of the button.

Comment: as you can see i have not set the height in the actual shape xml.. should i? because i set the height in my layout for the button to 40dp and no matter what i put the radius to it doesn't seem to change.. is their a way to set the radius to be dynamic?

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or emulator? If the button in your layout is 40dp, you want your corner radius to be 20dp. Try that on a real device and/or emulator and post a screenshot of what you get along with your layout xml file

Comment: hmm it appears you are right, and i had to actually publish to a device to see the expected/desired results.. wow was that a waist of time, thanks

Comment: No problem -- never trust the layout editor, it's a good "preview" but not necessarily a pixel-exact representation of what it'll look like on  a device

Answer (score 4):

You must specify every corner radius like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/green" />
    <size android:height="30dp" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        />
</shape>
```

You should not specify the width, so that it can adjust the width as background drawable.